# Configuring request model per endpoint in FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I have a [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) application, in which several endpoints require the same input model, but in each, some attributes may be optional while others are required. For example:

```
# file: app/schemas/models.py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class GenericRequestModel(BaseModel):
    id: UUID = None      # required by all endpoints
    attr1: str = None    # required by endpoint 1 and 2, optional for 3
    attr2: boot = None   # required by 2, optional for 1, 3
    attr3: int = None    # optional by all


# file: app/api/endpoints.py
from fastapi import APIRouter

router = APIRouter(prefix='/api')


@router.post('/endpoint-1')
def endpoint_1(params: GenericRequestModel) -> ResponseModel:
    return calc_response_using_all_attrs(params)

@router.post('/endpoint-2')
def endpoint_2(params: GenericRequestModel) -> ResponseModel:
    return return calc_response_using_attrs_1_and_2(params)

@router.post('/endpoint-3')
def endpoint_3(params: GenericRequestModel) -> ResponseModel:
    return calc_generic_response(params)
```

Is is possible to configure `GenericRequestModel`'s required property per endpoint, without deriving a new request models for each endpoint? If not, what is the most elegant solution?

**EDIT**
For completeness, here's the rationale behind my question. Assume you have many endpoints (say 50), and many attributes (100). Each endpoint may do complex stuff with the attributes and some endpoint can overcome missing data. Obviously, I don't want to create 50 different models.

Comment: Can you add more details about your use case, e.g., how many endpoints and attributes you have? Do I understand it correctly, that you want to do some sort of combinatorics per endpoint?

Answer (score 3):

The best thing that you can do here is: use inheritance. But you will need more than one model, e.g.

```py
from typing import Optional

from pydantic import BaseModel


class RequestModelBase(BaseModel):
    id: UUID
    attr1: Optional[int]
    attr2: Optional[boot]
    attr3: Optional[int]


class RequestModel1(RequestModelBase):
    attr1: int

class RequestModel2(RequestModel1):
    attr2: boot
```

Then you can use:

- `RequestModel1` for endpoint 1
- `RequestModel2` for endpoint 2
- `RequestModelBase` for endpoint 3

(I hope I understood your rules for required/optional attributes correctly.)

Comment: Thank @Rafael-WO, but this is exactly what I'm trying to avoid (assume I have 50 endpoints, not 3). BTW, if I were to use inheritance, I think you could just override the `Config` class in each mode, instead of re-creating attributes.

Comment: Hmm, I see... What about [dynamic model creation](https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/models/#dynamic-model-creation)? 
Not sure if it works with FastAPI and the Swagger docs though.
But if you want to have different response models per endpoint, I don't see a way of not defining different response models per endpoint (pun intended).

Comment: Because endpoints share most of the input parameters. Its just that they're not mandatory for every endpoint. I'll take a look at the dynamic thingy.

Comment: _How_ do you know which fields are optional and which are mandatory? If you're not going to write the definition anywhere, how would you know which are usable in which context?

Comment: I think this is absolutely the most reasonable solution. And much better than dynamic model creation. For an alternative approach using a **generic** model see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76413306/19770795). But keep in mind that it is restricted to specific use cases only and does not allow specifying different default values other than `None`.

Answer (score 1):

> *"Obviously, I don't want to create 50 different models."*

No, that is not obvious. If your schema is **different** (and yes, whether an attribute is required or not is an important schematic difference), then you need to provide a **different** model for that schema. I am not sure what else you expect.

Smart inheritance obviously will help to reduce code duplication to a minimum. But you cannot get around defining that schematic difference *somewhere*.

For maximum clarity the explicit inherit-and-override approach [by @Rafael-WO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76412429/19770795) is ideal. This also allows you to redefine potential default values for the overridden fields.

I guess technically another alternative is to use an actual [**generic model**](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/models/#generic-models) and specify the different types for those varying fields dynamically in each route handler function like this:

```py
from typing import Any, Generic, Optional, TypeVar

from pydantic.generics import GenericModel

T1 = TypeVar("T1", bound=Optional[str])
T2 = TypeVar("T2", bound=Optional[bool])


class GenericRequestModel(GenericModel, Generic[T1, T2]):
    id: int      # required by all endpoints
    attr1: T1    # required by endpoint 1 and 2, optional for 3
    attr2: T2    # required by 2, optional for 1, 3
    attr3: Optional[int] = None    # optional by all



from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.post('/endpoint-1')
def endpoint_1(params: GenericRequestModel[str, Optional[bool]]) -> dict[str, Any]:
    return params.dict()


@app.post('/endpoint-2')
def endpoint_2(params: GenericRequestModel[str, bool]) -> dict[str, Any]:
    return params.dict()


@app.post('/endpoint-3')
def endpoint_3(params: GenericRequestModel[Optional[str], Optional[bool]]) -> dict[str, Any]:
    return params.dict()
```

But it is important to note that this *only* works in this case because an annotation like `Optional[str]` (or equivalent `Union[str, None]` or `str | None`) receives **special treatment** by the Pydantic machinery and implicitly adds `None` as the default value making it an optional field. (Meaning you don't have to specify `attr: Optional[str] = None`, the `= None` is technically redundant.)

So something like `GenericRequestModel[Optional[str], Optional[bool]]` indicates to the model that both fields `attr1` and `attr2` not only allow `None` as a **value** for those fields, but also that `None` is the **default value**, if no value is passed at all.

This will **not work**, if you want to specify any default value other than `None` because that default must be defined explicitly during creation of the actual model. So if you for example want `attr1` to be *only* of type `str` and the field to have a default value of `"abc"`, there is no way to express that other than by explicitly defining that in the model namespace.

Which brings us back to the inheritance-based approach.